# BeautifulSoup doesn't find all div tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have started a private project: web-scraping with Python and BeautifulSoup in Visual Studio Code (1.41.0).

I was able to scrape another site with the same structure as my "problem site". However now I have encountered, that BeautifulSoup doesn't find all div tags (there should be 20 per site and I find just 3 of them). I have informed myself on Stack Overflow but did not find the solution (or obviously didn't understand it).

Website: https://www.comparis.ch/gesundheit/arzt/pathologie

The html structure I'm interested in looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I get all the `<div class="css-15dj4ut"></div>` from the `<div class="css-fh99y9 excbu0j0">...</div>` but none from the `<div class="css-roynbj excbu0j0"></div>`. Do you have any idea why?

In iterate over every url to get to each site.

```
for i in range(0, endIndex):
try:
    if i == 0:
        urls.append(basicUrl)
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[i])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        getSurgeonName(soup)

    else:
        urls.append(basicUrl + urlAddon + str(i + 1))
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[i])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        getSurgeonName(soup)

except:
    print("An URL request error occured.")
```

Function Version 1:

```
def getSurgeonName(soup):
    # gets just first 3 surgeons of site
    docName = re.compile('css-15dj4ut')
    docNameTags = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': docName})
    for a in docNameTags:
            docNameList.append(a.getText())
```

Function Version 2:

```
def getSurgeonName(soup):

    parentClass = re.compile('css-fh99y9 excbu0j0')
    parentItems = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': parentClass})

    for parent in parentItems:
           children = parent.findChildren('div', {"class": "css-15dj4ut"}) 
           docNameList.append(children[0].getText())

    parentClass = re.compile('css-roynbj excbu0j0')
    parentItems = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': parentClass})

    for parent in parentItems:
           children = parent.findChildren('div', {'class': 'css-15dj4ut'}) 
           docNameList.append(children[0].getText())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your desired `desired` data is loaded via `JavaScript` dynamically which the page loads, therefor `requests` package will not be able render `JavaScript` on the fly. But I've been able to locate the `script` tag which is holding the data in `string` of `JSON` `dict`, then loaded it into `JSON`.

Here you can parse whatever you want :).

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

r = requests.get("https://www.comparis.ch/gesundheit/arzt/pathologie")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
script = soup.find("script", {'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'}).text

data = json.loads(script)

print(data.keys())  # JSON Dict

dumper = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

print(dumper)  # to see it in human readble format
```

Something like:

```py
for item in data['props']['pageProps']['doctorResults']['doctorModels']:
    print(item['name'])
```

Output:

```
Mohamed Abdou
Dr. med. Heiner Adams
Dr. med. Franziska Aebersold
Prof. Dr. med. Adriano Aguzzi
Dr. med. Maria Ammann
Prosper Anani
Dr. med. Max Arnaboldi
Dr. med. Walter Arnold
Dr. med. Irena Baltisser
Dr. med. Fridolin Bannwart
Dr. med. Yara Banz
Dr. med. André Barghorn
Dr. Jessica Barizzi
Prof. Dr. med. Daniel Baumhoer
Audrey Baur Chaubert
Dr. med. Christian Georg Bayerl
Dr. med. Marc Beer
Dr. med. Sabina Berezowska
Dr. med. Steffen Bergelt
Dr. med. Barbara Elisabeth Berger-Denzler
```

Comment: Hey AHMED AMERICAN! Thank you very much for your fast response. I am very happy and grateful for your precious help! It works indeed like a charm. I have still to understand what happens exactly though (yes, you guessed right.... I am a novice :D) and which implications it has on my project. Nevertheless you helped me enormously!!! Thank you.

Comment: @MarcoRibolla you welcome, feel free to accept my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by ticking the check mark beside the question if it's helped you :P you can up-vote as well. glad to help

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη trying to implement this for another website since I cannot see the div-classes I need but I am unable to ('https://www.1stdibs.com/en-gb//dealers//en-gb/dealers/bernard-jacobson-graphics/shop/') I think the class I need is "_d2de3aa6"